# Is it dangerous to expose MongoDB's db.collection.find to users?

Tags: mongodb, security

I know in SQL land people love referring to [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) as the main reason to have a very strict interface between your user base and your database.

However, I want to implement a robust query solution using MongoDB, and it seems like I can theoretically give a user an interface that grants them full reign to what they want to query for.

The only danger I see is a user creating a long running query, which can be mitigated by using [$maxTimeMS](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/) with my `db.collection.find` query. Am I being naive?

I figure since `db.collection.find` forces queries to a particular collection, users would only have access to that collection. So they could only search in the `websites` collection, but not in the `users` collection.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is it depends, but most of the time this probably isn't a good idea. `SELECT` while it is less nefarious than other the other CRUD commands still carries risk.

### Why this is probably a bad plan

- Most applications with databases have some concept of an authenticated user vs a non-authenticated user. If I have unrestricted `SELECT` only access to the database I can find your hashed passwords and brute force the password offline.
- I can mine your database for your user's contact information to let them know about my buddy who is an African prince with a problem accessing his funds.
- I can DDoS your server by crafting long running queries and repeating them every timeout.
- I can create lots of memory intensive queries to drain resources as well
- I can scrape your data and use it for my own profit.
- I can increase your bandwidth costs by repeatedly requesting large amounts of data
- And many more things

It is important to note that even sites like [Have I been pwned?](https://haveibeenpwned.com/) which offer unauthenticated searches of large semi-public data sets don't allow unrestricted `SELECT` capabilities.

Comment: But in the MongoDB, when if I expose the find interface behind a REST interface; I can choose to only expose `find` on a particular collection. Is it a problem to give them access to the full breadth of find's query functionality on a particular collection? I only see this as a performance problem.

Comment: @Breedly "Only a performance problem?" If you don't care that a bad actor kills your response time for your users and you don't care that a bad actor drains your pocketbook via bandwidth costs, and you're absolutely sure that developers will never ever inadvertently allow access to privileged data via incompetence, errors, ignorance, and/or malice.... then yeah I see no problem with unrestricted read-only access.